# How to solve the DDNS exposure router management web dashboard issue?

Tags: networking, pi-4

Using the duck DNS.

I did the port forwarding, everything works well.

```
8888 => 192.168.10.2:80
```

One thing I found is that each time I visit the ddns url, it goes to my router management to ask password.

How do you solve this?

### BTW

The remote access of router has been disabled, disabling it doesn't help.

Comment: Depends on the router and its software, which router/software are you using ?

Comment: sorry, I don't know what is it exactly, something netcomm.

 it is from the ISP, but port forwading is supported and DDNS is running.

Comment: Why is port 8888 being forwarded to port 80 on 192.168.10.2 ? What happens if you go to the ddns url with :8888 appended to it ?

Comment: @Bra1n 

because port 80 is reserved for the router. `ddns.com:8888` is my local nginx, current problem is `ddns:com` is the router mnagement UI. which confuse me.

Comment: I'm also getting confused, what do you expect to happen when you visit the ddns url ?

Comment: `null` is my expected

Comment: Try forwarding port 80 which should send you to the forwarded LAN  ip if the router's management interface is disabled

Comment: thanks for the recommendation. I would like to try, my concern is that will my router admin page still available? if I do like that.

Comment: Only one way to find out